# How to answer Let's

Tags: american-english

> Let's go see a movie

If I can go, I can say, “Alright, OK, sounds good.”
If I can't go, I say, “I can't go, I have to...”

Right?

Comment: Right . . . .. . .

Answer (score 1):

Let's is a contraction of **Let us** so, in your example sentence, the person is really saying "*Let us go see a movie.*"  It is indeed a suggestion to go and view a movie together.

Note that, although it is phrased as a command, cultural convention is to interpret it as a suggestion.

So, to answer your question, either response would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple suggestion to which you can answer with:

- Let's
- Alright or Right
- Okay or OK
- Sounds good
- Sure thing or Sure

If you don't want to go:

- Can't, sorry
- Sorry, I cannot go
- Unfortunately I can't go